# How to assign multiple unique coupons to the same email using claimRow()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i have a question right now i am using the claimRow() for sending the coupon codes to the customers(email) through journey builder. Now the problem is no matter how many times they have been added to the journey they are getting the same coupon code now i want to send them a unique different for every entry.Hope someone will help me out

````
var @em, @couponRow, @couponCode
set @em = AttributeValue("emailAddr")
set @couponRow = ClaimRow("CouponCodes","IsClaimed","EmailAddress",@em)
if not empty(@couponRow) then 
set @couponCode = Field(@couponRow, "CouponCode")
endif
]%%```
````

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how Claimrow function selects and claims rows. The lookup is based on the last pairs of variables you provide in the function call. If a row already exists with this data, it will be selected. Otherwise a new row will be claimed.

In your example, you are only sending the email address:

```
ClaimRow('CouponCodes','IsClaimed','EmailAddress',@em)
```

As each time an email is sent to a given recipient, you will find the same row and re-send the same voucher code. You will need more parameters in your function call to ensure unique code will be sent to the same individual in each email, like this:

```
ClaimRow('CouponCodes', 'IsClaimed', 'JobID', JobID, 'ListID', ListID, 'BatchID', _JobSubscriberBatchID, 'EmailAddress', @em)
```

Comment: could you please help me out how to collect those job and list id's it would really helpful i am new to ampscript

Comment: Please read up on the documentation and examples out there. Here are few to begin with: [ampscript.xyz](https://ampscript.xyz/tips-and-tricks/how-to-claim-a-coupon-code/) [ampscript.com](https://ampscript.com/claimrow-function/) [sprignaturemoves.com](https://sprignaturemoves.com/coupon-claiming-in-ampscript/)

Comment: Also, the jobID, ListID, etc, are all personalisation strings, so they are automatically populated for you. For the complete list of personalisation strings, please check out [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thank you @Lukas i have tried your approach and it worked Thank you